# Need to migrate from SOAP based to RESTful Akamai Purge request format in TeamSite

Tags: java, rest, akamai, teamsite, interwoven

We have several Workflow tasks for a particular project in Interwoven TeamSite ,withing which the code for clearing webserver cache has been written.Webserver caching is actually happening via akamai purging(and currently the the akamai purge is using the SOAP based format).Since the SOAP based akamai purge format will soon get deprecated,we need to make necessary changes for migrating from SOAP based to REST API Akamai Purge format.Could you please help me to do this?I have gone through the following document: https://api.ccu.akamai.com/ccu/v2/docs/index.html

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? Making an HTTP request, creating a JSON body for it, auth, ...?

Comment: What I saw in the document was a Curl command ..that can be used for sending the Akamai Purge Request and also got the required response.I did this by running the Curl command in the destination web server(which happens to be a linux box) and hence it happened fine .But,what I believe is ..Curl command cannot be used in a windows box?I can I include this is my java code. Please help me as to how should I proceed with making the HTTP request,and creating a JSON body for it and also for authorization.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a perl script and call it from the external task in the workflow. Within the perl script make http rest calls to AKAMAI in order to purge. If you are not comfortable with perl scripts, you can call C# exes or java jars from perl script using *system* function. It is similar to running commands in cmd prompt or shell scripts.
2. If not you can create a servlet and call that servlet url from external task from workflow. Please refer manual. It requires creating JSPs, Adding bean tags in web.xml and building using maketoolkit.ipl. Within the servlet you can call AKAMAI rest api.
3. Let me know if you want to know, how to make http call in C# or Java.
4. Let me know if you want to know, how to create external task in workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I've just written a getting started guide for the CCU V2 API:

```
https://community.akamai.com/community/developer/blog/2015/08/19/getting-started-with-the-v2-open-ccu-api?sr=stream
```